# What programming language would I need to create a sign in and login form?

Tags: php, forms

What programming language would I need to create a sign in and login form?
Can I use only php to do that? I'm new to this area. So, any link referring to the procedure would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can do that and more with just PHP.  http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php,  There are plenty of tutorials out there on this subject, just search them up.

Comment: Yep!  https://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/

Comment: @SgtAJ, yes I need this type of sites. thanks. can you please refer me to any site to design sign up form too?

Comment: Just google: "PHP signup form".  You can google "PHP login form" to get more examples of the login form also.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, can i do it without mysql?

Comment: How would you store the passwords?  you would need a way to save them.  You can use other databases or storage means but typically MySql is the easiest for this.  It's not as hard as it looks, it just takes a bit of playing with to figure it out.  Use PDO or MySqli not  mysql_* functions they are being removed in future versions of php.

Comment: A good place to start is, download UniSever, that will give you a PHP, Apache, Mysql  setup on your computer and a essentially a complete web server test environment to play with.  http://www.uniformserver.com/

Comment: Another good thing to look into is Eclipse PDT, which is a free php IDE or editor with things like code completion, hints, and documentation.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, thanks. very helpful recommendations! BTW, is there any site with complete practical example of such forms?

Comment: @NadiaAli - hundreds of thousands of them, this one stack overflow has login forms, as dose facebook, pretty much any site you have to sign in to use  is a practical example, now if you want complete tutorials on how to program it, searching for them is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook, Stack Exchange, WordPress, Joomla are great websites. 
As they are great examples for the power of PHP.

User system is in fact the most important feature of any website.

PHP can interact with front-end languages. It can have HTML inside it, as CSS can be inside HTML. So, PHP can interact with wide number of languages including HTML and CSS.

I'm not saying its the best start but you can go to tutorialspoint.com and download the PDF version for PHP tutorial, that's where I started BTW. YouTube can also be your best friend with video tutorials. Good Luck.

Comment: I personally don't agree with the previous comments cuz I don't think telling a beginner to go and try to make a login form is a good idea. you first should grab the very basics.

Comment: thanks. can I do it without mysql?

Comment: @BenJunior - the only way to learn is to do, granted login and database stuff comes with a certain amount of security consideration that a novice programmer is likely to miss.   But you gotta start somewhere, I find it better to start with something practical then just randomly trying to learn the language.

Comment: @NadiaAli MySQL is an absolute necessity. Especially for login forms. And it isn't that much complex

Answer (score 1):

For sign up and login form you can use php language very well.And for the designing of the form you can use HTML and CSS.